# Only IE9 throwing error, ; is expected in ajax method.(SCRIPT1004: Expected ';')

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-9

Below is the jQuery ajax method I used for my ajax call. Firefox and Chrome are not throwing any console error. But IE9 is throwing:

> SCRIPT1004: Expected ';'

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    var ajaxUrl = "/ajax/loadpage";
    var os = "windows";
    var browser = "firefox";
    var lang= "en"; 
    var ajaxTimeout = 30000;
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: ajaxUrl,
        data: {'os' : os, 'browser' : browser,  'lang':lang}, 
        type : "POST",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        timeout: ajaxTimeout,
        beforeSend: function() {
            // added logic here
        },
        success: function(data) {
            // added logic here
        },
        complete: function(data) {
            // added logic here
        }
    });
});
```

If I remove two lines of code below, IE9 is not throwing that error.

```
data: {'os' : os, 'browser' : browser,  'lang':lang}, 
type : "POST",
```

Comment: Throws the error *when*?

Comment: @krillgar removed the spacing and checked.still console throw same error.

Comment: @DaveNewton throwing the error after execute the ajax call.

Comment: Then check what you're getting back, and include the "added logic" that's actually triggering the error.